# String parsing of multiple characters

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I'm trying to parse an NSString in a peculiar way and I can't figure out exactly how to do so (but I suspect it will require regular expressions). I have an NSString with some text with no whitespace at all such as: "Thisisatest". I need to get this text parsed into a series of two characters, preferably into an NSCountedSet because I will need the counts of their occurrences. In the above string the output would be: Th-1, hi-1, is-2, si-1, sa-1, at-1, te-1, es-1, st-1. I'll eventually need to do this for sets of three characters (Thi-1, his-1, isi-1,...) and sets of four characters (This-1, hisi-1,...). Being able to set whether or not to ignore case would be bonus. Thanks much!

Comment: Sounds great. Go right ahead and do that. What's the question?

Comment: Just walk the string picking up substrings by their NSRange (`substringWithRange:`). I don't see how regular expressions are involved. It's sheer brute force.

Comment: You might also find [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to be of use for this task.

Comment: @user1118321 How on earth would NSScanner have anything to do with this???

Comment: @matt My mistake - I have used `NSScanner` for string parsing before, but you're right, in this case it probably wouldn't be as useful. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Despite the OP's use of the word "parse" he is not in fact parsing anything. He's just picking up successive pairs of characters. That's not parsing; it's just counting (subdividing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. After much trial and error I got this to work:

```
NSCountedSet *digraphSet = [NSCountedSet set];

for (NSUInteger n = 0; n <= [text length]; n++)
{
    NSRange range;
    range.location = n;
    range.length = 2;

    if (n + 2 <= [text length])
    {
        [digraphsSet addObject:[text substringWithRange:range]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how trial and error is involved. What you did is exactly what I described in my comment - three days ago.